# undefined or null when using querySelector on a Element

Tags: javascript

here is the button that I click:

```
<a href="#" id="toggle|313746669218847_314159322510915" class="comment-reply comment-reply-default" role="button">
  <i class="fa fa-reply" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  <span>Reply</span>
</a>
```

I have this HTML Snippet That I get when I

```
const replyElement = document.getElementById("toggle|313746669218847_314159322510915").parentElement.parentElement;
```

resultant HTML snippet in `replyElement` after running the above line:

```html
<div class="parent-comment-chat-box comment-box">
  <div class="chat-user-name">
    <p><strong>A Dummy Page</strong></p>
    <p class="created-on">2018-11-28 07:17 PM</p>
  </div>

  <div class="parent_reply_block reply_block retry_block">
    <a href="#" id="toggle|313746669218847_314159322510915" class="comment-reply comment-reply-default" role="button">
      <i class="fa fa-reply" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      <span>Reply</span>
    </a>
    <div class="reply_text_area">
      <div class="comment-chatbox"><textarea placeholder="Reply…" id="comment-textarea" maxlength="7500" rows="2"></textarea></div>
      <div class="comment-menu"><input type="file" id="img_upload" class="hide" accept=".png, .jpg, .jpeg, .tiff">

        <div class="messages-btn">
          <span class="comment-indicator hide">
        <i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i>
        </span>
          <button id="active|main|0|-1|313746669218847_314159322510915" type="button" class="btn btn_darkblue messages_reply btn btn_darkblue messages_reply-default">
        <span>Send</span>
        </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now when I do `replyElement.querySelector('.reply_text_area')` I get `null`
And If go with the alternative `replyElement.document.getElementsByClassName('.reply_text_area')` I get `undefined`

Comment: You have no element with `id=some-id`. The first line if your JS doesn't work. Provide a real [mcve]

Comment: @Quentin Well first of all when I wrote the snippet replyElement  I also posted resultant snippet that I get in replyElement. I dont know why the heck did you edited that

Comment: Provide a real [mcve]

Comment: @HVenom If you select an element by its `id` and then get its parent, then that element with that `id` should be _in_ that parent. In your case it's not. If I add that id to the `<p>` surrounding the `<strong>A Dummy Page</strong>` then I get the element back just fine. Without an [mcve] we can't help you [because what you try to do works fine](https://jsfiddle.net/f4me7zbh/).

Comment: @Quentin The edits have been made

Comment: @HVenom — I cannot reproduce the problem if I copy/paste your code into an order where it actually runs: https://jsbin.com/pusonigeco/1/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your `replyElement` isn't there, because using `querySelector` to find the text area works:

I can only guess what your ID is supposed to be, but this works:

```js
const replyElement = document.getElementById('toggle|313746669218847_314159322510915').parentElement.parentElement;
var myElement = replyElement.querySelector('.reply_text_area');

console.log(myElement)
```

```html
<div class="parent-comment-chat-box comment-box">
  <div class="chat-user-name">
    <p><strong>A Dummy Page</strong></p>
    <p class="created-on">2018-11-28 07:17 PM</p>
  </div>
  <div class="fb_external_link"><a href="#" id="active|main|0|-1|313746669218847_314159322510915" title="Delete" class="action_button action_button-default" role="button"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a><span>|</span>
    <a class="external-target-link" target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/313746669218847_314159322510915"><i class="fa fa-external-link"></i></a>
  </div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
  <p>hello T
  </p>
  <div class="parent_reply_block reply_block retry_block"><a href="#" id="toggle|313746669218847_314159322510915" class="comment-reply comment-reply-default" role="button"><i class="fa fa-reply" aria-hidden="true"></i><span>Reply</span></a>
    <div class="reply_text_area" id="active|main|0|-1|313746669218847_314159322510915">
      <div class="comment-chatbox"><textarea placeholder="Reply…" id="comment-textarea" maxlength="7500" rows="2"></textarea></div>
      <div class="clear"></div>
      <div class="comment-menu"><input type="file" id="img_upload" class="hide" accept=".png, .jpg, .jpeg, .tiff">
        <a href="#" class="comment_camera comment_camera-default" role="button"><img title="Add Media" src="data:image/png;base64,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"
            alt="upload_button"></a>
        <div class="dropdown gif-block"><button id="menu1" type="button" class="btn feature_drowdownv2 dropdown-toggle gif-dropdown btn feature_drowdownv2 dropdown-toggle gif-dropdown-default"><img src="data:image/png;base64,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" alt="gif_button"><i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></button></div>
        <div
          class="messages-btn"><span class="comment-indicator hide"><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i></span><button id="active|main|0|-1|313746669218847_314159322510915" type="button" class="btn btn_darkblue messages_reply btn btn_darkblue messages_reply-default"><span>Send</span></button></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Well that's the exact issue `myElement` gives me null or undefined

Comment: What is the difference between your code and the snippet in my answer?